# Stack Exchange login dialog

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid, login

Is there any guide how to construct login dialog like [facebook dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but we have an API that includes a way to sign in to Stack Exchange sites: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication.